# DateDiff using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, datediff

I'm trying to use `DateDiff` in Entity Framework:

```
var data = (from e in _context.Employers
            join t in _context.Tickets on e.Id equals t.IdEmployer
            join i in _context.InfoClients on t.IdConnexion equals i.Id
            where t.Etat == "Encours"
            select new
                   {
                       t.DateCreation,
                       t.NumTicket,
                       i.IdConnexion,
                       datediff = DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)t.DateCreation).TotalDays,
                       t.SujetPrblm,
                       t.IdTicket,
                       e.Nom,
                       e.Prenom
                   }).ToList();
```

But I'm getting this error:

> This function can only be invoked from linq to entities

I also tried this but get the same error:

```
DateDiff = SqlFunction.DateDiff("Hour", t.DateCreation, DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: Are you using EF or EF Core? `SqlFunctions` for EF 6. `DbFunctions` for EF Core.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Both `SqlFunctions` and `DbFunctions` are for EF6. Ef-core has `EF.Functions`.

Comment: `EF.Functions` property returns `DbFunctions` class.

Comment: Sure but it's the return type, not entrance type. Your first comment is confusing because is suggests it's not available for EF6 (.Net framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `DateCreation`in select and then you can get the `DateTime.Now.Subtract` whenever you need later in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Function:

```
EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(StartDate,EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using DbFuntions.DiffDays() in my code this way:

```
...Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffDays(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BoxDate), DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DespatchDate)) > 2
                                                            && DbFunctions.DiffDays(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BoxDate), DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DespatchDate)) <= 4
                                                            && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DespatchDate) >= period
                                                            && x.Status == "Sent").Count();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try like

```
 DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract((yourDateTimeHere).Date).Days
```

and replace yourDateTimeHere.

Comment: `Subtract` cannot be translated from LINQ expression to SQL.

Comment: yees its not working

Comment: you can first select creationdate and calculate date difference later .